# How can I make monodevelop render text in KDE?

Tags: kde, slackware

Monodevelop from git in KDE 4.10.2 does not render text in code edit tabs [image: monodevelop run in xterm in kde - no text rendered, no errors]

I tried with xfce and text is rendered ok there.

I tried disabling composition with alt shift f12 and restarting x server but it was no better. 
I also tried disabling font softening in monodevelop options and disabling plugins.
I also tried temporarily deleting my KDE profile.

This is dual screen setup on Nvidia with nouveau. OS is slackware64-current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with oxygen-gtk theme. Change it to oxygen-molecule.

Comment: I only had original oxygen theme listed, but changing it to something else fixed the issue; tho now I don't have as nice rounded windows :)